# Provide multiple function arguments by one variable

Tags: r

When working with packages like `openxlsx`, I often find myself writing repetetive code such as defining the `wb` and `sheet` arguments with the same values.

To respect the DRY principle, I would like to define one variable that contains multiple arguments. Then, when I call a function, I should be able to provide said variable to define multiple arguments.

Example:

```
foo <- list(a=1,b=2,c=3)
  
bar <- function(a,b,c,d) {
  return(a+b+c+d)
}

bar(foo, d=4) # should return 10
```

How should the `foo()` function be defined to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you just looking for `do.call`? `do.call(bar, c(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), d = 4))`? Then `foo` would be `list`.

Comment: @Roland this is the cleanest and fully working solution yet. Please convert to an answer and I can accept it. Also updating the question to reflect that `foo` is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are just looking for `do.call`, which allows you to create and evaluate a call from a function and a list of arguments.

```
do.call(bar, c(foo, d = 4))
#[1] 10
```

Answer (score 0):

> How should the `foo()` function be defined to achieve this?

You've got it slightly backwards. Rather than trying to wrangle the output of `foo` into something that `bar` can accept, write `foo` so that it takes input in a form that is convenient to you. That is, create a *wrapper function* that provides all the boilerplate arguments that `bar` requires, without you having to specify them manually.

Example:

```
bar <- function(a, b, c, d) {
  return(a+b+c+d)
}

call_bar <- function(d=4) {
  bar(1, 2, 3, d)
}

call_bar(42)  # shorter than writing bar(1, 2, 3, 42)
```

Comment: In many cases, this would be a perfectly good answer because the values of `a`, `b`, and `c` are static. But if we, for example, have an expanded grid of 3 values of `a`, 3 of `b`, and 3 of `c`, we'd need to define 27 different `call_bar_##` functions with the currently suggested solution. An example of where the values change could be a `for` loop of `openxlsx´ sheets and you are doing many operations on each sheet within that loop.

Comment: Also, if I want to do many operations in `openxlsx` with numerous functions, for example, I'd need to define many different wrappers to fit with the different functions I'm calling with the current structure of `call_bar`

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution using [`rlang::exec`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/exec.html).

First, we must have a function to structure the dots:

```
getDots <- function(...) {
  out <- sapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], function(x) eval(parse(text=deparse(x))))
  return(out)
}
```

Then we must have a function that executes our chosen function, feeding in our static parameters as a list (`a`, `b`, and `c`), in addition to `d`.

```
execute <- function(FUN, ...) {
  dots <- 
    getDots(...) %>% 
    rlang::flatten()
  out <- rlang::exec(FUN, !!!dots)
  return(out)
}
```

Then calling `execute(bar, abc, d=4)` returns `10`, as it should do.

Alternatively, we can write `bar %>% execute(abc, d=4)`.

Answer (score -3):

***Let me give you an example!
How to get two or more return values ​​from a function***

Method 1: Set global variables, so that if you change global variables in formal parameters, it will also be effective in actual parameters. So you can change the value of multiple global variables in the formal parameter, then in the actual parameter is equivalent to returning multiple values.

Method 2: If you use the array name as a formal parameter, then you change the contents of the array, such as sorting, or perform addition and subtraction operations, and it is still valid when returning to the actual parameter. This will also return a set of values.

Method 3: Pointer variables can be used. This principle is the same as Method 2, because the array name itself is the address of the first element of the array. Not much to say.

Method 4: If you have learned C++, you can quote parameters

***You can try these four methods here, I just think the problem is a bit similar, so I provided it to you, I hope it will help you!***

Comment: This answer is gibberish